# Why am I getting an error when sending invoices to XERO?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Wordpress website running WooCommerce and I am using a plugin called XERO to do my invoicing, whenever I try and send an invoice to XERO via Wordpress back end the website throws an error:

> Fatal error: Class 'WC_XR_OAuthSimple' not found in /home/vipcomau/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-xero/classes/requests/class-wc-xr-request.php on line 213

So here is the the snippet of code where this error refers to:

```
    private function get_signed_url() {
    if ( null === $this->signed_url ) {

        // Setup OAuth object
        $oauthObject = new WC_XR_OAuthSimple();

        // Reset, start clean
        $oauthObject->reset();

        // Settings object
        $settings = new WC_XR_Settings();

        // Do the OAuth sign request
        $oauth_result = $oauthObject->sign( array(
            'path'       => self::API_URL . $this->get_endpoint() . '/',
            'action'     => 'PUT',
            'parameters' => array(
                'oauth_signature_method' => 'RSA-SHA1'
            ),
            'signatures' => array(
                'consumer_key'    => $settings->get_option( 'consumer_key' ),
                'shared_secret'   => $settings->get_option( 'consumer_secret' ),
                'rsa_private_key' => $settings->get_option( 'private_key' ),
                'rsa_public_key'  => $settings->get_option( 'public_key' ),
                'oauth_secret'    => $settings->get_option( 'consumer_secret' ),
                'oauth_token'     => $settings->get_option( 'consumer_key' )
            )
        ) );

        // Set the signed URL
        $this->signed_url = $oauth_result['signed_url'];

    }

    return $this->signed_url;
}
```

I am really struggling with this as I am not a PHP developer but setting the website up for a client.

Comment: Integrating with Xero is a decent job to take on for someone who isn't a PHP developer! That error basically means your Xero library isn't available to PHP directly, perhaps it doesn't follow the namespacing rules that Wordpress might use for autoloading, or perhaps you need to "include"/require the files first manually

Comment: @scrowler Yeah I think I've bitten off more than I can chew! Ok so do you think I could just put a simple "include" in the code linking to my "class-wc-xr-OAuthSimple.php" file?

Comment: That would work, but it's probably not best practice. I don't know much about Wordpress unfortunately, so can't advise how the autoloader works.

Comment: xero needs cURL and curlSSL need to be installed on your server, do you have ssl on your website?

Comment: @omerFarooq ahh ok, I currenlty don't have SSL on the website. Once SSL is on the site will XERO correct itself?

Comment: Yes it should work fine.